# android - Not the same interface display on different screens

Tags: android, layout

I'm new in android programming and my problem is that i created a simple calculator interface with some LienarLayouts and the result is not the same on the design display and my physical phone.

[The result i get on the design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGHvd.png)

[The result i get on my phone (Galaxy S7)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1axu.png)

I couldn't find any solutions for that. For the operators it's some images that i put on different drawable folders (hdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi).

i will put my xml file here.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="165dp"
            android:background="@color/clrBlue"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="50dp"
                android:text="567"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textSize="45sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="87dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:text="7"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:text="8"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:text="9"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/divide" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="87dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:text="4"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:text="5"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:text="6"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/multiply" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="87dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:text="2"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:text="3"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/subtract" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="192dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button15"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/clrBlue"
                    android:text="clear"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/add" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:paddingTop="125dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/equal" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What you want to achieve looks like a task for TableLayout

Comment: Think that the problem is using static dimensions in your button and linearLayout.

Comment: Yes i used some static dimensions on buttons, but i thought when using density pixels it makes it fit in all screen sizes

Answer (score 0):

The result is different because of the different sizes. At the top of your layout display you will see that Nexus 4 is selected which is of screen size 4.7" and I think Galaxy S7 is of size 5.1".

Also, there can be a difference in density pixels.
You can refer to the android document for different pixel densities.
[Support Different Pixel Densities](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate!
i've seen the difference on the screen size, but how can we solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Relative and Linear layouts is not best choice for create calculator layout. To make this layout try use `GridLayout` or `ConstraintLayout`. It will be easier and more reliable solution

**Edited**

[image: calculator layout]

Comment: Thanks for the answer man! So to make it fit in all screens i have to avoid LinearLayouts?

Comment: @SalimHallouche Shortly, yes. LinearLayout great tool for ordering views by vertically or horizontally, not both

Comment: Oh i understand now. Thanks a lot i'm gonna try with the GridLayout